# How to create method to use "_changed?" on combined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have a method that combines several address fields like so:

```
def address
    "#{street_address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{postal_code}, #{country}"
end
```

How would I extend the method to allow for the checking if any of the fields have changed?  Basically, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address.changed?
```

My model is as follows:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :postal_code, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :geocode_type
  geocoded_by :address

  after_validation :geocode#, :if => :address.changed?

  def address
    "#{street_address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{postal_code}, #{country}"
  end
end
```

Or is there a better way to do this all together?

Comment: code the method yourself. I can't see anything better

Comment: Keep in mind `:if => :address.changed?` does not make any sense as there's no method `changed?` on Symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def address_changed?
  attrs = %w(street_address city state postal_code country)
  attrs.any?{|a| send "#{a}_changed?"}
end
```

Comment: Yep... I would go for this kind of solution. Mayybe using the attrs array for the address method too :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of using send unless absolutely needed.  I've come to like explicit coding.

Answer (score 2):

A little clunky...

```
def address_changed?
  street_address_changed? || city_changed? || state_changed? || postal_code_changed? || country_changed?
end
```